# Using PHP remove duplicates from an array without using any in- built functions?

Tags: php

Lets say I have an array as follows :

```
$sampArray = array (1,4,2,1,6,4,9,7,2,9)
```

I want to remove all the duplicates from this array, so the result should be as follows:

```
$resultArray = array(1,4,2,6,9,7)
```

But here is the catch!!! I don't want to use any PHP in built functions like `array_unique()`.

How would you do it ? :)

Comment: How would *you* do it? Have you put any thought in it?

Comment: Just wondering but why don't you want to use `array_unique()`? academic reasons?

Comment: Yes . Was asked this question during a job interview today. So, I have been thinking, what is the best way to solve it.

Comment: If the question was phrased in this way -- expressly asking not to use a builtin -- then the answer is to use a built-in function and to find a place to work where *using the tools provided by the language* is standard practice.

Comment: @Felix I would do it as @Stijntjhe has answered below :)

Comment: @user626333: While this works, there are better solutions ;)

Comment: @Felix Yes .Of course there are :) May be much more efficient and optimized. @Charles yes, he wanted me not to us any built in functions. May be I think he wanted to test my programming skills. But, he had a lot of ego issues and came off as very arrogant.

Comment: @Scorpyon Had the same question in an interview, what an absurd assessment of practical development skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A serious (working) answer:

```
$inputArray = array(1, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 9, 7, 2, 9);
$outputArray = array();

foreach($inputArray as $inputArrayItem) {
    foreach($outputArray as $outputArrayItem) {
        if($inputArrayItem == $outputArrayItem) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $outputArray[] = $inputArrayItem;
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

Comment: Yup it works :) I was thinking along the same line. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I made a small modification to prevent continuing to search when a duplicate has been already found (inner foreach). Additionally the duplicate flag variable is not needed.

Comment: in case anybody looking what is continue 2  please read here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431162/2191252

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple O(n)-time solution:

```
$uniqueme = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $uniqueme[$value] = $key;
}
$final = array();
foreach ($uniqueme as $key => $value) {
   $final[] = $key;
}
```

You cannot have duplicate keys, and this will retain the order.

Comment: note: will only work if the values are strings or integers (and even then strings with integer values will not have their type preserved because they will be converted to integers).

Comment: @Artefacto: Indeed, thanks for the hint. Same here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/G6pNpA  -- which means array keys can only be used as integer hashes. I wonder how array_merge behaves -- the same: http://codepad.org/3g2Htar4

Comment: Yes this is the exact solution and less complexity

Answer (score 2):

**Edit2:** The versions below use a hashmap to determine if a value already exists. In case this is not possible, here is another variant that safely works with all PHP values and does a strict comparison ([**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/crDDKd)):

```
$array = array (1,4,2,1,6,4,9,7,2,9);

$unique = function($a)
{
    $u = array();    
    foreach($a as $v)
    {
        foreach($u as $vu)
            if ($vu===$v) continue 2
        ;
        $u[] = $v;
    }
    return $u;
};

var_dump($unique($array)); # array(1,4,2,6,9,7)
```

---

**Edit:** Same version as below, but w/o build in functions, only language constructs ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/vExJfk5Y)):

```
$array = array (1,4,2,1,6,4,9,7,2,9);
$unique = array();
foreach($array as $v)
  isset($k[$v]) || ($k[$v]=1) && $unique[] = $v; 

var_dump($unique); # array(1,4,2,6,9,7)
```

And in case you don't want to have the temporary arrays spread around, here is a variant with an anonymous function:

```
$array = array (1,4,2,1,6,4,9,7,2,9);

$unique = function($a) /* similar as above but more expressive ...                   ... you have been warned: */ {for($v=reset($a);$v&&(isset($k[$v])||($k[$v]=1)&&$u[]=$v);$v=next($a));return$u;};

var_dump($unique($array)); # array(1,4,2,6,9,7)
```

---

*First was reading that you don't want to use `array_unique` or similar functions (`array_intersect` etc.), so this was just a start, maybe it's still of som use:*

You can use [`array_flip` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) in combination with [`array_keys` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for your array of integers ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/Qc47yTid)):

```
$array = array (1,4,2,1,6,4,9,7,2,9);

$array = array_keys(array_flip($array));

var_dump($array); # array(1,4,2,6,9,7)
```

As keys can only exist once in a PHP array and `array_flip` retains the order, you will get your result. As those are build in functions it's pretty fast and there is not much to iterate over to get the job done.

Comment: "I don't want to use any PHP in built functions like `array_unique()`"

Comment: as @tandu said, I don't want to use any PHP built in functions

Comment: well those functions are not like array_unique :). Will show the same w/o any functions at all.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the operations you have available.

- If all you have to detect duplicates is a function that takes two elements and tells if they are equal (one example will be the `==` operation in PHP), then you must compare every new element with all the non-duplicates you have found before. The solution will be quadratic, in the worst case (there are no duplicates), you need to do `(1/2)(n*(n+1))` comparisons.
  If your arrays can have any kind of value, this is more or less the only solution available (see below).
- If you have a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) for your values, you can sort the array (`n*log(n)`) and then eliminate consecutive duplicates (linear). Note that you cannot use the `<`, `>`, etc. operators from PHP, they do not introduce a total order. Unfortunately, `array_unique` does this, and it can fail because of that.
- If you have a hash function that you can apply to your values, than you can do it in average linear time with a hash table (which is the data structure behind an array). See 
  tandu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$inputArray = array(1, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 9, 7, 2, 9);
$outputArray = array();

foreach ($inputArray as $val){
 if(!in_array($val,$outputArray)){
  $outputArray[] = $val;
 }
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate array into which you add each item in turn.  prior to adding the item you could check if it already exists by looping through the new array.