# continue 2 and break in switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am new to PHP and saw the code below online. It has `continue 2` and `break` together in `switch/case` statement. What does it mean?

```
foreach ( $elements as &$element ) {

    switch ($element['type']) {
        case a :
            if (condition1)
                continue 2; 
            break;

        case b :
            if (condition2)
                continue 2;
            break;
    }

    // remaining code here, inside loop but outside switch statement
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `continue 2` skips directly to the next iteration of the structure that is two levels back, which is the `foreach`. The `break` (equivalent to `break 1`) just ends the `switch` statement.

The behavior in the code you've shown is:

Loop through `$elements`. If an `$element` is type "a" and `condition1` is met, or if it's type "b" and `condition2` is met, skip to the next `$element`. Otherwise, perform some action before moving to the next `$element`.

---

From [PHP.net:continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

> *continue* accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default
>   value is 1, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.

From [PHP.net:switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

> PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch
>   block, or the first time it sees a break statement.

> If you have a switch inside a loop and wish to continue to the next
>   iteration of the outer loop, use continue 2.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. So, you mean,  if the type is "a" and condition1 is met or if the type is "b" and condition2 is met, the remaining code in loop which outside switch statement will not be executed and will jump to next iteration in the loop, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `continue 2` skips directly to the next iteration of the `foreach` loop without executing any code after the `switch`. [Here's a demonstration.](http://viper-7.com/4SkL9L)

Comment: Get it. Thanks for kindly explanation.

Comment: My link above is dead. Here's a [replacement](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1de4fdb55ed8eb2c56d5ab48eb981847821c4f82)

Answer (score 4):

continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default value is 1, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Answer (score 2):

continue and break are similar in that the will stop something from happening.

in case of continue, it will stop anything after the braces but won't stop the loop. The switch statement just gets out of this statement and goes on to the next statement.

In case of break it will stop the entire loop from continuing, end the loop there.